# Usage of "will now" in Scientific writing?

Tags: grammar, present-tense, future-constructions

My advisor and I are writing a research paper. I have a doubt in the following sentence that he wrote.

> We will now prove Theorem 1.
>
> *proof follows...*

The words 'will' and 'now' are contradictory here. 'Will' is used for the future tense and 'now' is used for the present. I replaced the sentence with:

> We now prove Theorem 1.
>
> *proof follows...*

Am I correct or both the usages are correct? Also, which one is more formal?

Comment: "We will now do *X*" is perfectly natural and idiomatic.

Comment: @randomhead But aren't the words: 'will' and 'now' contradictory with respect to tenses?

Comment: It is in fact not "technical writing" for a research paper but "Scientific writing".

Comment: @Brad I thought both terms meant the same.

Comment: No, well not anymore.  Here is a definition; The traditional definition says technical writing can be defined as the practice of articulating any product or service in the form of the document where processes are defined, such as software manuals or instructional materials. In earlier days, it was limited to user manuals type only.
The modern definition says Technical Writing is an art and science of writing niche that specialized in giving details about how things work and preparing others through documentation to carry out precise tasks for accomplishing preferred objectives or tasks

Answer (score 1):

The "will" says the proof will happen in the future. The "now" says it's in the immediate future: right now, the next thing in the paper.

You could leave out the "will" without changing the meaning. If you leave out the "now" but proceed directly to the proof the reader may be a little puzzled.

Both your sample sentences are correct. Neither is more formal than the other. I would omit "will" just to use one fewer word.

Comment: This has nothing to do with English language per se but use of English in scientific writing.

Answer (score 0):

*Usage of “will now” in technical writing?* I believe this should be

> **Usage of “will now” in Scientific writing?**

As the writing has a strict format the use of will now is not permitted in this context.

---

> The research question can also be formulated as a research aim or objective (e.g. “The
> aim/objective of this study is to determine the age of the …. Formation”) or as a
> hypothesis (“We hypothesise that the …. Formation is of Middle Jurassic
> age”). In earth
> science, stating a research aim is more common than stating a research
> question or a hypothesis.

**Introduction**

**“The objective of this study is to prove Theorem 1”**

THIS IS THEN FOLLOWED BY

**Method**

**Results**

**Discussion/conclusion**

**Other necessary content**

Ref [A guide for scientific writing](https://students.uu.nl/sites/default/files/ge0-aw-guide-for-scientific-writing-2016.pdf)